# Display Table values in Pdf page with TCPDF

Tags: javascript, php, pdf, tcpdf

We are using below php & javascript code to display values inside table.

[image]

**php**

```
function getDesignerCollection(){
    $stmts = $user_home->runQuery("SELECT * FROM tbl_users WHERE userID=:uid");
    $stmts->execute(array(
        ":uid" => $_SESSION['userSession']
    ));
    $rows = $stmts->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    $stmt = $user_home->runQuery("SELECT * FROM order_details");  
    $stmt->execute(array(":uid" => $_SESSION['userSession']));
    $row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    $stmt->execute();

    $accountType = $rows['type'];
    if ($accountType == "admin"){
        $is_admin = true;
        $order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->getCollection()->addAttributeToFilter('designer_id', array(
            'nin' => '0'
        ));
    }
    /* Fetching magento db details end */       

    $i = 0; 
    foreach($order as $orderData){ 
        $k = 0; 
        $orderitems = $orderData['dproduct_id']; 
        $orderitemsarray = explode(",", $orderitems); 

        while ($k < count($orderitemsarray)){ 
            if ($orderitemsarray[$k] != '0'){ 
                $stmtorders = $user_home->runQuery("SELECT * FROM order_details"); 
                $stmtorders->execute(array(":dorder_id" => $orderData['entity_id'])); 
                $roworders = $stmtorders->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); 

                if($accountType == "admin"){ 
                    $designerName = getDesignerName($productdetail->getDesignerID()) . " -(" . $productdetail->getDesignerID() . ")"; 

                    while($datas = $stmt1->fetch()){
                        $paid_status=$datas['dpaid_status'];
                        $delivery_status=$datas['delivery_status'];
                    }
                    $responce[] = array( 
                        $orderData->getIncrementId() , 
                        $orderitemsarray[$k], 
                        $productdetail->getName() , 
                        $designerName, 
                        $orderData['status'],  
                        $orderData['grand_total'],
                        $orderData['customer_email'], 
                        $commission, 
                        $paid_status, 
                        $delivery_status,
                        $due_date,
                        $sDate
                    ); 
                }
                $k++; 
                $i++; 

            }   
            return json_encode($responce);  
        }
```

**script**

```
var __TEST_DATA__=eval('<?php
echo getDesignerCollection(); ?>');
var grid_demo_id = "myGrid" ;

    var colsOption = [
       {id: '' , header: "" , width :"15",renderer : my_renderId , width :"60"}, 
        {id: 'created_at' , header: "Order Date" , width :"100"},
        .
        .
       {id: 'delivery_status' , header: "Delivery Status" , width :"110"},
       {id: 'due_date' , header: "Payment Due Date" , width :"140"},

    ];
```

Now i added "button" in  php page , once we click on button, it should display table in pdf format. for that i am using TCPDF & trying below code.
once i click on "button" its redirecting to Pdf page, but its not displaying values present in table.

[image]

```
$html = <<<EOD
<h1>Welcome</h1>
EOD;

$html='<table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="border:1px solid #e1e1e1">';
        $html.='<tr bgcolor="#cccccc" ><th  height="20" >Commission</th><th>Paid status</th><th>Delivery date</th><th>Due date</th></tr>';
        foreach ($order as $orderData)
        {
            if(is_array($order[0]))
            {

                foreach ($order as $orderData)
                {
                    if($i%2==0){ $html.='<tr bgcolor="#d3d6ff">';}else{ $html.='<tr>';}

                    $html.='<td  height="20" >&nbsp;'.$commission.'</td>';
                    $html.='<td>'.$paid_status.'</td>';           
                    $html.='<td>'.$delivery_status.'</td>';
                    $html.='<td>'.$due_date.'</td>';                      
                    $i++;             
                    $html.='</tr>';          
                } 
            }
            else
            {
                if($i%2==0){ $html.='<tr bgcolor="#d3d6ff">';}else{ $html.='<tr>';}

                    $html.='<td  height="20" >&nbsp;'.$commission.'</td>';
                    $html.='<td>'.$paid_status.'</td>';           
                    $html.='<td>'.$delivery_status.'</td>';
                    $html.='<td>'.$due_date.'</td>';                   
                $i++;             
                $html.='</tr>';
                }                
        }

        $html.='</table>';


    // Print text using writeHTMLCell()
    $pdf->writeHTMLCell(0, 0, '', '', $html, 0, 1, 0, true, '', true);
```

full code : http://pastebin.com/P5DinusU , i am new to php & tried lot before posting question here.

Comment: what is in $order? i think is it empty array

Comment: @VijayaVigneshKumar we are fetching values of paid status , commission & due date from order_details table.... please check full code once : http://pastebin.com/P5DinusU

Comment: could you please print_r($order); and paste the result here

Comment: mean i need that array

Comment: i have one doubt could you please clear that

Comment: what is the purpose of if(is_array($order[0]))?? to change the tr background color am i right?

Comment: @VijayaVigneshKumar when we tried this [code](http://www.w3schools.com/php/showphpfile.asp?filename=demo_db_select_oo) i can able display `order_details` table values in php page. also

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a hidden input filed in your form and add you html structure in its value. On submit get it from post and add it into your PDF html you are creating.
For which You need to add this code into your export form

```
<form action="#" name="pdfForm" method="POST">
<?php
     $order=json_decode(getDesignerCollection(),true);
     $html="";
     foreach ($order as $orderData)
     {
         $html.='<tr>';
         $html.='<td  >'.$orderData[8].'</td>';
         $html.='<td>'.$orderData[9].'</td>';
         $html.='<td>'.$orderData[10].'</td>';
         $html.='<td>'.$orderData[11].'</td>'; 
         $html.='<td>'.$orderData[12].'</td>';
         $html.='<td>'.$orderData[1].'</td>';
         $html.='<td>'.$orderData[3].'</td>';
         $html.='</tr>';
     }
   ?> 
  <input name="order_data" type="hidden" value='<?php echo ($html); ?>'/>
  <button type="submit1" name="submit1" value="Submit"> Export To PDF    </button>
   </form>
```

After adding it just remove that from your PDF code and make that like it

```
$html='<table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="border:1px solid #e1e1e1">';
    $html.='<tr bgcolor="#cccccc" >
    <th>Commission</th>
    <th>Paid status</th>
    <th>Delivery date</th>
    <th>Due date</th>
    <th>order date</th>
    <th>order id</th>
    <th>product name</th></tr>';

     $html .= $_POST['order_data'];
  $html.='</table>';
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<?php
    $html="<table border='0' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='0' style='border:1px solid #e1e1e1'>";
    $html.="<tr bgcolor='#cccccc'><th  height='20'>Commission</th><th>Paid status</th><th>Delivery date</th><th>Due date</th></tr>";
    $i=0;
    if (count($order)>0) {
        foreach ($order as $orderData)
        {
            $bgcolor=($i%2==0)?"#d3d6ff":"";
            $status=($orderData['status']==0)?"Inactive":"Active";
            $tbl="<tr bgcolor='".$bgcolor."'>";                    
            $tbl.="<td height='20'>&nbsp;".$commission."</td>";
            $tbl.="<td>".$paid_status."</td>";           
            $tbl.="<td>".$delivery_status."</td>";
            $tbl.="<td>".$due_date."</td>";                      
            $tbl.="</tr>";          
            $html.=$tbl;
            $i++;
        }
        $html.="</table>";
   }?>
```

Comment: could you please send me the array of order

Comment: when i tried `print_r($order); ` before `return json_encode($responce);` ,  its hiding the table

Comment: `$responce[] = array( 
$orderData->getIncrementId() , 
$orderData->getIncrementId() , 
$orderitemsarray[$k], 
$productdetail->getName() , 
$designerName, 
$orderData['status'], // magento [ pending / processing/complete] 
$orderData['grand_total'], // magento 
$orderData['customer_email'], // magento 
$commission, 
$paid_status, 
$delivery_status,
$due_date,
$sDate // magento 
); `

Comment: i tried your code, its displaying same result as [here](http://sbdev2.kidsdial.com:81/php/site6/vijaya.php#) email : kidsdial1@gmail.com , pw : kidsdial1

Comment: remove the exit; and print_r($order);

Comment: $order definitely returns the array

Answer (score 0):

```
        if(is_array($order))
        {

            foreach ($order as $orderData)
            {
                if($i%2==0){ $html.='<tr bgcolor="#d3d6ff">';}else{ $html.='<tr>';}

                $html.='<td  height="20" >&nbsp;'.$commission.'</td>';
                $html.='<td>'.$paid_status.'</td>';           
                $html.='<td>'.$delivery_status.'</td>';
                $html.='<td>'.$due_date.'</td>';                      
                $i++;             
                $html.='</tr>';          
            } 
        }
        else
        {
            if($i%2==0){ $html.='<tr bgcolor="#d3d6ff">';}else{ $html.='<tr>';}

                $html.='<td  height="20" >&nbsp;'.$commission.'</td>';
                $html.='<td>'.$paid_status.'</td>';           
                $html.='<td>'.$delivery_status.'</td>';
                $html.='<td>'.$due_date.'</td>';                   
            $i++;             
            $html.='</tr>';
         }                

    $html.='</table>';


// Print text using writeHTMLCell()
$pdf->writeHTMLCell(0, 0, '', '', $html, 0, 1, 0, true, '', true);
```